# Does "the partial" (1 Cor 14:10b) allude to the imperfect nature of the "Spiritual gifts" or refer to the imperfect users and their use?

Tags: word-study, 1-corinthians

Context: 1 Cor 13:8-12 (ESV)

> <sup>**8**</sup> Love never ends. As for prophecies, they will pass away; as for tongues, they will cease; as for knowledge, it will pass away. <sup>**9**</sup> For we know in part and we prophesy in part, <sup>**10**</sup> but when the perfect comes, **the partial** will pass away. <sup>**11**</sup> When I was a child, I spoke like a child, I thought like a child, I reasoned like a child. When I became a man, I gave up childish ways. <sup>**12**</sup> For now we see in a mirror dimly, but then face to face. Now I know in part; then I shall know fully, even as I have been fully known.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to "what is partial" in 1 Cor 13:10 is found in 1 Cor 13:9 -

> **9** For we know in **part** and we prophesy in **part**, **10** but when the perfect comes, the **partial** will pass away.

That is, the partial refers to incomplete and imperfect knowledge/prophecy. As the Cambridge commentary succinctly observes:

> 9. **and we prophesy in part** All inspired utterances are but partial revelations of Divine Truth.

Similarly, Poole observes:

> **For we know in part**; it was truly said, as to things human, that the greatest part of those things that we know, is the least part of
> those things which we are ignorant of. A great measure of Divine
> things is also unknown to us, and the knowledge of them reserved for
> thr resurrection and day of judgment, John 14:20.
>
> **And we prophesy in part**; nor can the communication of our knowledge to that, be larger than what we by prophecy communicate; we
> having ourselves but a short and imperfect communication of Divine
> things, we can communicate but an imperfect degree of knowledge to
> others.

While ever we are still human and have imperfect human minds and bodies (as distinct from the heavenly bodies promised in 1 Cor 15:39-51), nothing can be complete or perfect.  We have imperfect knowledge, imperfect/incomplete revelation of God, imperfect/partial understanding of spiritual things, etc, etc.